# How do I ensure that my function always returns my generated connection object?

Tags: java, database, odbc

I have to do a task for my university where I should write a function that returns a connection to a database. I create a new Connection object in the try block and now want to return it, but i need to ensure that my function always returns a connection even if i land in the catch block. How do I write a function that always returns a connection? I have tried to use finally, but the variable cn only exists in the try block.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Properties;



public class ConnectDB {
    
    final String propfile = "/properties/db.properties"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectDB con = new ConnectDB();
        con.connect();
        
    }
    public Connection connect() {
        
        try {
            final java.io.InputStream propFile = new ConnectDB().getClass().getResourceAsStream(propfile);
            final Properties props = new Properties(System.getProperties());
            props.load(propFile);   
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(props.getProperty("url"), props.getProperty("user"), props.getProperty("password"));
            return cn;
        }
            
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("connect ERROR :\n" + e.toString());
        }
          
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't: an exception was thrown because it was impossible to create a Connection. You can return null, but that is just going to result in a harder-to-diagnose error when the caller tries to use it. Instead, get rid of the try/catch entirely and let `connect` throw an exception. This will report the cause of the problem at the earliest opportunity.

Comment: Since you cannot guarantee that no failure will happen, you really only have two choices: return a value that says "failed" instead of the expected connection object (null is a popular choice), or don't return inline: throw an exception, or equivalently don't intercept the exception that someone further down the stack already threw. I'd go with the exception.